# Does this stopping time always have infinite first moment?

Tags: probability, martingales

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables with zero mean and let $S_n := X_1 + \ldots + X_n$. Does $T := \inf\{n: S_n > 0\}$ always have infinite first moment?

In the trivial case, where $X_i = 0$, we have $T = \infty$. For random walk, in which $X_i = \pm 1$ with probability $1/2$, it can be shown that $\mathbb{E}[T]=\infty$. I am wondering if it is always the case that $\mathbb{E}[T]=\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. This follows indirectly from the optional stopping theorem. The relevant formulation of the theorem says the following. If $X_n$ is a martingale, the increments of $X_n$ are "conditionally bounded", and $\mathbb{E}(\tau) < \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau]=\mathbb{E}[X_0]$. "Conditionally bounded" means that $\mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1}-X_n| \, | \mathcal{F}_n) \leq C$ independent of $n$.

Here $S_n$ is a martingale because it is a sum of iid variables and its increments are conditionally bounded by $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|]$. So the first two hypotheses hold. Now by contraposition, since the conclusion fails, the third hypothesis must also fail. That is, since $\mathbb{E}[S_\tau] > 0$ while $\mathbb{E}[S_0] = 0$, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\infty$.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by 'on average you are moving to the right'. In the problem, we assume $E[X_i]=0$, which means the expected moving distance is $0$. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @roy_24601 Sorry, I missed the zero mean requirement.

Comment: @roy_24601 I've corrected my post now.

Comment: In my case, the increment in the martingale might not be bounded. The problem didn't assume anything on $X_i$ other than being mean zero.

Comment: @roy_24601 Sorry, what you actually need is that they are "conditionally bounded", meaning that $\mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1}| | \mathcal{F}_n) \leq C$ for a fixed $C$ independent of $n$. I think this follows from integrability of the $X_n$.

Comment: The proof sounds good to me except the the theorem you quoted. Could you please tell me any reference regarding the theorem? Thanks!

Comment: @roy_24601 The Wikipedia article on the optional stopping theorem mentions this formulation and provides a proof. Note that technically in your setting you should also use the conditional Jensen inequality to say that $\mathbb{E}[|S_{n+1}-S_n| \, | \mathcal{F}_n] \leq \mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1}|)$.

Comment: @Ian: I think the conditionally boundedness is simple because $E(|X_{n+1}|\mid \mathcal{F}_n) = E(|X_{n+1}|)$ since $X_{n+1}$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_n$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Siméon: This is because $S_T > 0$ by the definition of $T$.

Comment: @Siméon: I don't understand. $T$ is the smallest $n$ such that $S_n > 0$, and so $S_T > 0$. Therefore $E[S_T] > 0$. I don't see any problem with this argument.

Comment: @roy_24601: of course you're right, sorry. I was thinking at something else.

Comment: Just to bring useful, the implication $\Bbb E[T] < \infty \Rightarrow E[S_T] = 0$ follows directly from [Wald's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#General_version), which is kind of a special case of the optional stopping theorem.

Comment: @Siméon Nice catch! You're right, that is an easier proof in roy_24601's case.